# What is smallest solution of ${10}^{2x} \equiv 1 (\textrm{mod p})$, when p is a prime number and x $\in$ $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$?

Tags: number-theory

What is smallest solution of ${10}^{2x} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, when p is a prime number and x $\in$ $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ ?

Comment: Non-negative solution?: $\;x=0\;$ ....${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What does $2*x$ mean, if not $2x$?

Comment: Sorry, x should be positive integer, I have edited the question.

Comment: $2*x$ is same as $2x$

Comment: Are you given $p$ and seeking the smallest $x$, rather than the other way around? The question is not written well due to a lack of quantifiers. Anyway, there is no simple answer for the smallest $x$. It is what it is (some factor of $p-1$).

Comment: If $p=2$ or $p=5$, then there is no positive integer solution.

Comment: It is the order of $100$ mod $p,\,$ which by Fermat divides $\,p-1\,$ for primes $\,p\nmid 10.\,$ It has no nice closed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on $p$.

For example, prime divisors of $99$ are $3$ and $11$, so the solution is $1$ for these primes.

Prime divisors of $9999$ are $11$, $101$ and $3$, so the solution is $2$ for $p=101$.

Prime divisors of $999999$ are $3$, $7$, $11$, $13$ and $37$ so the solution is $3$ for $p\in\{7,13,37\}$.

And so on.

Of course there is no solution for $p=2$ and $p=5$.

The number of primes for each solution is finite, and little Fermat's theorem implies that the solution divides $p-1$, but little more can be said.

Comment: Can you prove how $x$ divides $p-1$?

Comment: LFT implies that $100^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$. If $x$ is the least positive integer such that $100^x\equiv 1\pmod p$, use Euclidean division to write $p-1=qx+r$ where $0\le r<x$. Then $100^{qx+r}=(100^x)^q\cdot 100^r\equiv 1\pmod p$. Therefore $100^r\equiv 1\pmod p$. Since $r<x$, then $r=0$, that is, $x$ divides $p-1$.

Comment: Actually, you can do better, $x\mid \frac{p-1}2$. Let $d$ be order of $10$ in $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$. Then $d\mid p - 1$. If $d$ is even, set $x = d/2$ and thus $x\mid \frac{p-1}2$. If $d$ is odd, set $x = d$. Then $x\mid\frac{p-1}2\cdot 2$, but $x$ is odd, so none of the prime factors of $x$ divides $2$, i.e. $x\mid \frac{p-1}2$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) tells us that for $a,n$ coprime, $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\bmod n$, and recall also that for prime $p$,  [$\phi(p)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $=p-1$. Note that this means that $a^{k(p-1)}\equiv 1\bmod p$.

Euler also assures us that if $a,n$ have a common factor, then $a^{k}\not\equiv 1\bmod n$ for any $k>0$, so for $p=2,5$ there is no such $x$ to satisfy the question.

For $p=3$, $10\equiv 1 \bmod p$ and thus $10^k\equiv 1 \bmod p$ for all $k\ge 1$ giving the result of $x=1$ for the question (and the divisibility test for $3$).

So given $p>5$, the smallest value occurs at some value when $2x \mid p\mathord-1$ $\implies$ $x \mid \frac{p-1}2$. The largest value it can occur $x=\frac{p-1}2$ and the factors of $\frac{p-1}2$ can be tested to see if a lower value is available.

For example, for $p=71$, $\frac{p-1}2=35$ and the possible values of $x$ are $\{5,7,35\}$. $100^5\equiv 30 \bmod 71$ and $100^7\equiv 25 \bmod 71$ so $x=35$ must be the correct answer.